# Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_COOKIE_VARS nd Undefined index:Mycookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie  and set its values but getting the above errors

```
<?php
$value='chhaya';
setcookie("Mycookie",$value);
//time()+1800 means cookie will expire in half an hour
setcookie("chhaya","ralph",time()+1800,"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\","",1);
echo $_COOKIE["Mycookie"];
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["Mycookie"];
?>
```

Comment: $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS is undefined. $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS [deprecated] used $_COOKIE http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Basically you can't access a cookie you just set since cookies are only sent with each page request. So it actually doesn't exist yet.

Also, [`$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php). You should *not* be using it.